# OSError errno 13 Permission Denied Python CGI os.listdir

Tags: python, linux, apache, cgi

I am executing os.listdir() from Python CGI script. Script executes from console with no problem but when it is called from the web interface I get OSError errno 13 Permission Denied. It is denying permission to files in a different directory /usr/local/bin/ I checked permission levels and even changed owner and group to apache. I Even added Apache Directory configurations to allow all in ssl.conf file. Any thoughts? Thank you all in advance for the guidance.

Comment: The CGI script may not be executing as the apache user/group. You might try creating a file in python and seeing what user/group permissions are on the file. SELinux may also be restricting what you're able to do, so you may want to temporarily disable it.